# Why does a deamon process need a new sid?

Tags: linux

Taken from this: http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html#ss4.4

```
From here, the child process must get a unique SID from the kernel in order to operate. Otherwise, the child process becomes an orphan in the system.
```

What's the matter if the child process becomes an orphan? Why does it need his own sid?

Comment: well, the existing session and associated environment it was executing under would vaporize, leaving it unable to execute properly.

Comment: @FrankThomas Hi Frank, thanks for the comment. Could you please be more clear? What do you mean with associated environment? What happens if I leave a deamon process as orphan? I knew that the init process would take care about childs without a ppid

Comment: every process is created by a user, an inherits that users environment (for instance ~ for a process under user1 points to user1's home, but for user2 would point to user2's home), and access rights. a child process takes on the user of its parent. how does a process access a folder if that process no longer has a user associated with it? That is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Nix processes are identified by a PID (process ID) a PPID (parent's PID), a GID (Group ID), and an SID (Session ID). You can see them with the command

```
 ps  xao pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm
```

(this includes the `command` field, *i.e.* the command that gave rise to the process).

PID and PPID are easy to understand; the GID is used to allow an interrupt to reach all processes belonging to the same group: suppose you are doing

```
find / -type f -name '*.pdf' | sort | less
```

and you want to `suspend` this command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) you will need to suspend all of them; to allow this, they belong to the same GID and the interrupt is delivered to all processes with the same GID.

The SID (session ID) is the PID of the process that creates a session. All processes later created within the same session inherit this SID, though they may have distinct Group IDs and PPIDs, and they certainly have distinct PIDs.

When the session in question terminates (for instance thru a logout), the kernel kills all processes with the same SID, belonging to the session in question. This is done for obvious reasons: the processes left about would be waiting for input which cannot arrive any more, or they would be delivering output or error messages which no one will look at.

In order for a service (my earlier answer did not take into account that you are discussing exactly a service, sorry about my absent-mindedness) to survive the logout of the session that started it, it cannot be left with the SID of the original session, lest it be mowed down by the kernel at logout. Hence the need for a new SID. If you do not assign it a new SID, it will inherit that of the session which runs it, and will be killed whenever that session is closed, which is most likely much shorter than how long you would like a service to last.

There is another standard (but yet cute) twist in the page you referred to above: the `fork`. This too is part of the strategy for the daemon to survive the disappearance of its originating environment. You have probably noticed that the daemon first forks from its parent process, then it immediately closes the parent process before starting to work. Why? Because, when a terminal is closed,  it sends a SIGHUP signal to its controlling process, the shell. This usually causes all process attached to this shell to die, as the shell will retransmit the SIGHUP it received to all its jobs.But the shell does not keep track of its *grandchildren*, hence the daemon survives the closing of the terminal from which it originates.

Detaching the daemon from the Session and from the terminal is essential to its survival, once either one disappears.

Comment: Hi Marius, so why when creating a deamon it needs a new sid? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @FedericoPonzi, on a practical level, you fork a process to handle a new activity, so depending on how the daemon is written, each process represents a parallel operation by the daemon, be it a user session, an atomic request/response stream, or a set of parallel working processes. Any given daemon may be served by multiple processes, but the parent child relationship of those processes needs to be carefully manipulated to ensure that each process has an executing environment, a parent, etc. For parallel operations, its even  sometimes advantageous to have separate environments.